# Performance impact of not implementing relationships at the database level?

Tags: database, performance, relationships

Let's imagine a data model with customers and invoices. There is a 1 to n relationship between a customer and its invoices. We uses an ORM (like Hibernate).

One can explicitely implement the 1-n relationship (using JPA for example) or not. If not, then one must do a bit more work to fetch invoices.

However, it is much easier to maintain, improve and develop the data model of applications where relationships between objects are not explicitely implemented in the database.

My question is, has anyone noticed a significant performance impact when not implementing the relationships in the database?

Comment: There is no such thing as "relationship in the database". They are all atomic values with either constrainst or local indexing.

Comment: @Euphoric - I think it's reasonable to call the effect of foreign-key constraints (which I assume is what the OP is referring to) "relationship[s] in the database".

Comment: Indeed this is what I refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I implement a relationship like that, there are 2 parts to it:

1. The "foreign key"
2. The "index"

The foreign key is a constraint which says that the `CustomerId` in the `Invoice` table must exist in the `Customer` table.  This (probably) doesn't give you any performance improvement (in fact there's a performance hit to do the check), but it's there to catch errors and make absolutely sure that the data is consistent.  Weird things can happen.  I don't suggest skipping this.

The index is when you index the `Invoice` table by the `CustomerId` column.  I know that in SQL Server you have to specify this separately from the foreign key.  The index will give you a performance improvement, if you ever look up invoices for a given customer.  However, maintaining the index takes time and space, so there's a tradeoff.